# Looking for regular expression that matches the first part of a URL fragment

Tags: javascript, regex, url-fragment

I have a URL fragment like 'users/123/edit' and I would like to match the first part of the string (in this case 'users'). The URL fragment could also be just 'users' and it should also match 'users'.

I could do it via JS **find()** and **substr()**, but I would like to see, how I do it via a Regular Expression. An explanation to the solution would be nice aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex :

```
str.match(/[^\/]*/i)[0]
```

this matches all characters different then (before) "/"

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NX5JA/)

Answer (score 2):

**Regex: `/([a-z0-9]+)(\/[a-z0-9]+)*/i`**

**Matches:**

1. `users/123/edit`
2. `users`
3. `myuser123`  // tell if not required

**Explanation:**

`([a-z0-9]+)` catches one or more occurrences (`+`) of `[a-z0-9]` and captures it.

`(\/[a-z0-9]+)*` catches zero or more occurrences (`*`) of `/` followed by `[a-z0-9]` and captures the last occurrence.

The `i`gnore case flag makes the entire match case-insensitive.

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cZ6xW3)**

Comment: I accepted radia's answer, because it only matched the required base-part. Still, thanks for the good explanation!

Comment: @johnny No problem at all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split('/')[0]`:

```
s = 'users/123/edit'.split('/')[0];
// users
```

OR else:

```
s = 'users'.split('/')[0];
// users
```